# VBA, Calculation for multiple worksheets/workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Macro:

```
Sub PercentCalc()

Dim xrng As Range, lrw As Long, lrng As Range, i As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

For i = 1 To 25
    With Columns(i)
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End With
Next

lrw = Columns("A:Y").Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row
Set lrng = Range("A" & lrw + 2)

With Range("A2:A" & lrw)
    lrng.Formula = "=COUNTA(" & .Address(0, 0) & ")/ROWS(" & .Address(0, 0) & ")"
End With

Set xrng = Range(lrng, Cells(lrng.Row, "Y"))

lrng.AutoFill xrng, Type:=xlFillDefault
xrng.Style = "Percent"

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With 
End Sub
```

How can I apply this across multiple worksheets in a workbook? Or multiple workbooks with multiple worksheets? I have a macro to open all Excel files in my directory. Even better if I could bypass opening all Excel files.

Pretty much want to automate this macro within a large amount of files/sheets.

Comment: Basically you need 2 loops around this macro or in another sub, calling this macro, 1 the loops through all the excel files that are valid, and the second that loops through all the valid sheets.

Comment: Create the function in a module within one "driving" workbook.  That driving workbook can iterate over the files and sheets you're interested in and apply the function for each of them.

Comment: You're doing everything on the active sheet. If you want to handle a bunch of sheets (eg. loop through them as suggested) you can reference them by name or number like this. `Worksheets("Sheet2") ` so you can do stuff like `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(lrng, Cells(lrng.Row, "Y"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't calculate without opening all the workbooks, but there is a simple command for what you are looking for: `Application.CalculateFull`. It re-calculates all sheets in all open workbooks. Be aware that this may take a long time and may make Excel seem like it is not responding until it finishes. In addition, if the open sheets are in a different instance of Excel from your macro above, they will not calculate.

So I would imagine your process to look like this:

- Run your macro to open all the files
- Run your macro above, with `.CalculateFull` just after `.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` and just before `End With`, `End Sub`